# How to get ConTeXt to display page numbers with chapters in both TOC and footers?

Tags: table-of-contents, page-numbering, context

I would like page number appear in both the Table of Contents, and page footers, just like in old Manuals from Digital Equipment Corporation. That is Chapter#--Page#, where pages restart at 1 with each chapter. This is the best I have:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,location=]
\starttext

% with \headnumber[chapter], page number in TOC appears as "-1".
% with \determineheadnumber[chapter]\currentheadnumber, page numbers in
%   TOC appear as "0-1"
\define[1]\addchapterprefix{\headnumber[chapter]--#1}
\defineconversion[addchapterprefix][\addchapterprefix]
\definestructureconversionset[frontpart:pagenumber][][romannumerals]
\definestructureconversionset[bodypart:pagenumber][][addchapterprefix]
\setuppagenumber[way=bychapter,numberconversionset=pagenumber]

\setuplist[chapter][alternative=f,style=\ssb]
\setuplist[section][alternative=c,pageconversionset=pagenumber]
\setupfootertexts%
    [{{\bf\userpagenumber}~~\getmarking[chapter][first]}]%
    []%
    []%
    [{\getmarking[chapter][first]~~{\bf\userpagenumber}}]

\setuphead[chapter][page=right]
\setuphead[section][number=no,style=\ssb]

% with \startsectionblockenvironment[frontpart] ConTeXt fails to produce
%   any output, or error message.
\startfrontmatter
\startchapter[list=Table of Contents]
\setupinterlinespace[small]
\placecontent[criterium=all]
\startsection[title=Preface]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
\setcounter[userpage][1]

\startchapter[title=This is my chapter title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\startsection[title=This is my section title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=This is another chapter title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\startsection[title=This is another section title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter

\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```

I've used `\startfrontmatter` over `\startsectionblockenvironment[frontpart]` because ConTeXt cycles once with the latter, and produces no output or error message. The calling of the page conversion seems to work with `\startfrontmatter`, only I can't find any place that the chapter number is defined at the time of producing the table of contents.

Using ConTeXt version 2019.03.21 21:39, LuaTeX version 1.10.0 (Tex Live 2019) on macOS 10.14.6.

Answer (score 1):

You mix up the following two commands:

- `\startsectionblock[⟨NAME〉] ... \stopsectionblock` and
- `\startsectionblockenvironment[⟨NAME〉] ... \stopsectionblockenvironment`.

The `sectionblock` environment is the same as the `bodypart` environment but you pass the name of the *sectionblock* as argument of the start-command. The `sectionblockenvironment` environment is used to set options which are used at the begin of a certain *sectionblock* and you put it in the preamble of your document.

To get the *chapter* value in front of the page number you have to enable the *prefix* for the `userpagenumber` (the `\setuppagenumber` command is a synonym for `\setupuserpagenumber`).

```
\setupuserpagenumber
  [way=bychapter,
   prefix=yes,
   prefixset=chapter,
   prefixsegments=chapter]

\setuppagenumbering
  [alternative=doublesided,
   location=none]

\setupfootertexts
  [{\prefixedpagenumber\hspace[medium]\getmarking[chapter][first]}]
  []
  []
  [{\getmarking[chapter][first]\hspace[medium]\prefixedpagenumber}]

\setuplist
  [chapter]
  [alternative=f]

\setuplist
  [section]
  [alternative=c,
   pageprefix=yes,
   pageprefixsegments=chapter]

\defineconversionset [frontpart:pagenumber] [] [i]
\defineconversionset  [bodypart:pagenumber] [] [n]

\setuphead
  [section]
  [number=no]

\starttext

\startfrontmatter

\completecontent

\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter

\dorecurse{2}
  {\chapter{Chapter \convertnumber{word}{#1}}
   \dorecurse{4}
     {\section{Section ##1}
      \dorecurse{3}{\samplefile{weisman}}}}

\stopbodymatter

\stoptext
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question (although, I'm not entirely sure why this works). It relies upon `\setupuserpagenumber[ prefixsegments=chapter ]` which is missing from most documentation:

```
\setuppagenumbering[alternative=doublesided,location=]
\starttext

\definestructureprefixset[pageprefix][chapter][] % ch--pg in \userpage footers
\setuplist[chapter][alternative=f,style=\ssb]
\setuplist[section][alternative=c,pageconversionset=pagenumber]
\setupfootertexts%
    [{{\bf\userpagenumber}~~\getmarking[chapter][first]}]%
    []%
    []%
    [{\getmarking[chapter][first]~~{\bf\userpagenumber}}]

\setuphead[chapter][page=right]
\setuphead[section][number=no,style=\ssb]

\startfrontmatter
\setupuserpagenumber[numberconversion=romannumerals]

\startchapter[list=Table of Contents]
\setupinterlinespace[small]
\placecontent[criterium=all]
\startsection[title=Preface]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter
\stopfrontmatter

\startbodymatter
\setupuserpagenumber[way=bychapter,prefix=yes,
            prefixsegments=chapter, % ch--pg in ToC
            prefixset=pageprefix,   % ch--pg in \userpage footers
            numberconversion=numbers]
\setcounter[userpage][1]

\startchapter[title=This is my chapter title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\startsection[title=This is my section title]
\dorecurse{10}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter

\startchapter[title=This is another chapter title]
\dorecurse{20}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\startsection[title=This is another section title]
\dorecurse{20}{The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.\par}
\stopsection
\stopchapter

\stopbodymatter
\stoptext
```